# Solving the inequality $1+1.2 + 1.2^2 + 1.2 ^3 + \cdots + 1.2^n < N/16?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, geometric-series

Given the inequality $$1+1.2 + 1.2^2 + 1.2 ^3 +\cdots + 1.2^n < \frac{N}{16}?$$

I need the value of $n$, or just an approximation. $N$ is known.

Comment: Yes, is 1.2. I will correct.

Comment: So what is the value of $N$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  $1.2+1.2^2+1.2^3+\cdots+1.2^n$ is a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)

Comment: This is not clear.  Is $n=N$?  $\quad$

Comment: The left hand is a geometric series.  It sums to $\frac {1.2^{n+1}-1}{1.2-1}$.  Not sure if that helps you or not.  I expect you'll still need to solve the problem numerically.

Comment: Any, per hour N can be 30.

Comment: No, n it is other than N.

Comment: Are you asking for the largest $n$ such that the left hand is less than the right hand?

Comment: Note:  If $N=30$ the problem is trivial, no?

Comment: After working out the geometric series and isolating $1.2^{n+1}$, you can take a logarithm of both sides to isolate $n$.

Comment: $$n < \dfrac{\ln \dfrac{N}{80}}{\ln 1.2}-1$$

Comment: Presumably the dots here stand for multiplication, so $1.2$ on the LHS of the inequality means $1 \times 2 $ not $6/5$.

Comment: @RobArthan  I am reading, e.g., $1.2^n$ as $(1.2)^n=\left( \frac 65\right)^n$.  Perhaps the OP should confirm or correct.

Comment: @Lulu: On reflection, you are probably right. But let's see what the OP has to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the formula for the partial sum of a geometric series, rewrite this as
$$
\frac {1.2^{n+1}-1}{1.2-1} < \frac N{16} \implies
5(1.2^{n+1}-1) < \frac N{16} \implies
1.2^{n+1} < 1 + \frac N{80}.
$$
If we take a logarithm, we can solve this exactly to get
$$
n < \frac{\log(1 + \frac N{80})}{\log(1.2)} - 1.
$$
For a numerical approximation, we can note that $1.2^{n+1} \geq 1 + (0.2) \cdot (n+1)$, so that $n$ will necessarily satisfy the inequality if 
$$
1 + \frac{n+1}{5} < 1 + \frac{N}{80} \implies n < \frac{N}{16} - 1.
$$

Comment: We could also get closer approximations by using Taylor expansions for $\log(1 + x)$ in the numerator and denominator of $\frac{\log(1 + \frac N{80})}{\log(1.2)}$.

Comment: Well, but for larger $N$ it follows that $n$ is $O(\log N)$

Comment: Sorry, you are probably right. I'll delete my comment on your answer and we'll see what the OP says in response to the comments on the question.

Answer (score 0):

$1+1.2+1.2^2+\ldots +1.2^n = \frac{1.2^{n+1}-1}{1.2-1}$ $= 5(1.2^{n+1}-1)$.

So you want to find the values of $n$ such that the inequality

$$5(1.2^{n+1}-1) < \frac{N}{16}$$

This gives

$$1.2^{n+1} < \frac{N}{80} - 1$$

Taking logs this gives

$$n \log 1.2 < \log \left(\frac{N}{80}-1\right)$$

which as $\log 1.2 < .2$ and $\log 80 \approx .4.4$ , will hold for large $N$ if the following is satisfied:

$$.2n < \log N - 4.5$$

or $$n < 5 \log N - 18$$